# Add text at end of needle of Half pie chart - D3 with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, charts

I am using D3.js for half pie chart in Angular 12 app. I added needle, but I want to have text at end of needle to show the value as in the image
[Needle with Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0tiA.png)

I got needle, but unable to render the value at the end of needle.

My code

```
this.svg = d3
          .select('div#pie')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width',this.svgWidth)
          .attr('height',this.svgHeight)
          .attr('id','pie-svg') 
          .append('g')
          .attr('class','ps')
          .attr(
            'transform',                
            'translate('+this.svgWidth/2+',115)');
                       
this.colorRanges = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(['a', 'b', 'c'])
.range(this.colors)    

this.pie = d3
.pie()
.startAngle(-90 * (Math.PI / 180))
.endAngle(90 * (Math.PI / 180))
.value((d: any,i:number) => d[1])
.sort((a:any, b:any) => d3.ascending(a[0], b[0]));

this.svg.selectAll('rect')  
.data(this.pie(Object.entries(this.pieData)))
.join('path')
.attr('d',
d3.arc().innerRadius(75).outerRadius(35))
.attr('fill', (d:any,i:number) => this.colorRanges(d3.schemeSet2[i]))
.attr('stroke','none')
.style('stroke-width','1px')
.style('opacity',1);    

this.svg
  .selectAll('.needle')
  .data([0])
  .enter()
  .append('line')
  .attr('x1', -10)
  .attr('x2', -75)
  .attr('y1', 0)
  .attr('y2', 0)
  .classed('needle', true)
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(135)');
```

I tried adding few codes as below from internet and failed.

```
var labelArc = this.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(75)
  .innerRadius(35);

  this.svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d: any) {
  return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text("75");
```

As I am new to D3 and Angular, unable to proceed.

Could someone please help to get the text on top of needle.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with appending a new "g" which inserts new graphic, the position could be near the needle, but would need some workarounds.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some code samples.

Comment: `this.svg.selectAll("circle1")  
      .data(data)  
      .enter()  
      .append("circle")  
        .attr("fill", "#7B1E99")  
        .attr("r", 3)  
        .style("opacity", 0.5)  
        .html("<span> Text: </br>" + d.value + "</span>")`

This basically adds a circle and puts the html content mentioned inside the circle.